# Как скачать полученное фото в TelegramBot?

Tags: java, telegram-bot

Есть задача скачать фото которое было отправлено боту. Пытаюсь делать и в результате появились вопросы. Вот так скачиваю:

```
if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasPhoto())
     {

    long chat_id = update.getMessage().getChatId();
    List<PhotoSize> photos = update.getMessage().getPhoto();

    String f_id = photos.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PhotoSize::getFileSize).reversed())
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null).getFileId();



    GetFile getFileRequest = new GetFile();
    getFileRequest.setFileId(update.getMessage().getPhoto().get(0).getFileId());
    org.telegram.telegrambots.api.objects.File file = getFile(getFileRequest);

    File f_path = new File("https://api.telegram.org/file/bot"+getBotToken()+"/"+file.getFilePath());

    String caption = "file_id: " + f_id + "\nfile_path: " + f_path;

    SendPhoto msg = new SendPhoto()
            .setChatId(chat_id)
            .setPhoto(f_id)
            .setCaption(caption);
    try {
        sendPhoto(msg);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
```

И появились вопросы: 1.Что в этом коде можно убрать? На мой взгляд это какой-то быдлокод получился. 2. Что использовать вместо

```
getFile(getFileRequest);
```

т.к он объявлен устаревшим.
3. Почему переходя по полученной ссылке, я скачиваю фото которое уменьшено? Т.е отправил 800*600, а скачиваешь чуть ли не аватарку. Но отправляет обратно нормальный размер. Может кто-то поделится нормальным рабочим кодом?

Comment: По поводу скачиваемого размера:  По непонятной для меня логике, за размер отвечает отвечат параметр get(). Поменял на getPhoto().get(3).getFileId() и размеры стали нормальными.

Comment: Но это ещё зависит от фото. Надо ставить последнее число. Но как получить сколько этих чисел?

Comment: Получилось вот так get(photos.size()-1)

Answer (score 0):

```
bot.downloadFile(raw, src);
```

- `raw` — фото, которое нужно скачать. Например: `msg.photo[3].file_id;` скачивает третье фото в массиве, т. е. оригинал фото (без сжатия).
- `src` — путь, куда должно загрузиться фото. Например: `'./src/photos/'`.

Answer (score 0):

Изначально, когда пользователь присылает боту сообщение с прикреплённой фотографией, она некоторое время хранится где-то там, у них.

При помощи объекта `PhotoSize` вы можете узнать некоторые данные об этом файле.
Изначально вы получите `file_id`, `file_unique_id`, ну и многие другие поля, кроме `file_path`

У вас появляется значение `file_id`, которое вы сможете использовать.

В библиотеке TelegramBot есть метод `GetFile(String file_id)`, засовываем туда наш идентификатор.

После чего запускаем метод `bot.execute(getFile)` - он вернёт вам объект `File`
(он вообще много чего, оказывается, возвращает, полезно прочесть сигнатуры этого метода)

Далее, уже у этого объекта `File` (не из JDK, а из Telegram) уже будет `file_path`.

Всё что нужно сделать теперь, это вызвать в боте метод `downloadFile(file, dir)`

В указанной директории будет лежать нужное вам фото.

Код с примером прилагается (скачиваю все фотографии, прикреплённые пользователем)

```
    public void processMessage(Update update)
    {
        if (update.hasMessage())
        {
            Message message = update.getMessage();
            Chat chat = message.getChat();

            if (message.hasPhoto())
            {

                List<PhotoSize> photos = message.getPhoto();
                int count = 1;
                for (PhotoSize photo : photos)
                {
                    GetFile getFile = new GetFile(photo.getFileId());
                    try
                    {
                        File file = bot.execute(getFile); //tg file obj
                        bot.downloadFile(file, new java.io.File("photos/photo" + count + ".png"));
                        count++;
                    } catch (TelegramApiException e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

И да, когда пользователь отправляет сообщения, телеграм сжимает их под разные размеры файла (до конца не знаю, для чего, поэтому не скажу).

Однако, они сохраняют и исходный файл, и сжатый, и сильно сжатый.
(У меня их 4 вышло, при загрузке большой картинки).

Из Message вы получаете `List<PhotoSize>` - каждый `PhotoSize` соответствует отдельному файлу с собственным качеством.

Успехов!